# Как при выборе города, получить код страны и саму страну?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

```js
var pac_input = document.getElementById('location_city');
$(function() {
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(pac_input);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&amp;libraries=places&amp;language=ru&amp;key=AIzaSyCSJmcUclvlj25FmDdGS8GMdr_3wkTv2Y8"></script>
<form action="" class="search-delivery">
  <input type="text" name="city" id="location_city" placeholder="Москва">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    for(var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
        var address = place.address_components[i];
        for(var j = 0; j < address.types.length; j++) {
            if (address.types[j] === 'country') {
                console.log(address.long_name);
            }
        }
    }
});
```